# Does this definition of equality to a class really require a substitution of variables?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the work of William A. R. Weiss on set theory (2008), [An Introduction to Set Theory](http://www.math.toronto.edu/weiss/set_theory.pdf), it is said on page 16 that:

> We write $\quad v_k = \left\{ v_j : \Psi \right\}\quad$ instead of $\quad(\forall v_l)((v_l \in v_k) \longleftrightarrow \Psi(v_j|v_l))$

Why not simply say the following instead (which is simpler, at least in my point of view)?

> We write $\quad v_k = \left\{ v_j : \Psi \right\}\quad$ instead of $\quad(\forall v_j)((v_j \in v_k) \longleftrightarrow \Psi)$

I'm asking because although it seems correct to me, Weiss says that variable substitution might seem a trivial thing but it is very important in some cases, so perhaps I am missing something. Thanks!

Comment: IMO is only a "nitpicking" issue : with the symbol $\Psi$, we have no idea **if** variable $v_j$ occurs in it.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but the same author uses $\Psi$ alone in the last two sentences (same page). Also $\Psi$ is used alone freely in the class definition $\left\{ v_j : \Psi \right\}$, so I think there is more to it...

Comment: Frankly speaking, I'm quite uncomfortable with that approach... I've browsed the first pages and nowhere I've found that "a string of symbols of the form $\{ v_i : \Psi \}$ is defined as a "legitimate" expression of the language. Thus, we have to wait for someone clever than me to comment :-)

Comment: He is being sloppy lazy with the notation.